# TASM - How can I push a normal word-sized register into the floating point stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, tasm, x87

I'm trying to use the floating point stack for calculation, however, I'm having some trouble pushing values to the stack.

I've tried casting with a double word floatHelper variable using

```
mov [floatHelper], dword ptr [cx]
fld [floatHelper]
```

```
mov word ptr [floatHelper], cx
fld [floatHelper]
```

```
fild [cx]
```

and all of them failed, with various error messages.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want int->FP conversion, you need `fild` (or use SSE instead of obsolete x87 at all).  There is a form of `fild` / `fistp` that works for a 16-bit integer operand.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fild.  You get assemble-time errors (instead of just runtime) because `fld` doesn't support 16-bit floating point memory operands.

Comment: @PeterCordes So, if floatHelper is size word, I can do
`mov [fStackHelper], cx | fild [fStackHelper]`
right?

Comment: Yes.  You could have tried it yourself before asking me.